# Ms-Chart Label Format Question

Tags: c#, formatting, mschart

I created a PieChart with the new Ms Chart Controls. How can I format the Labels (Point Values inside the Pie) like the folllowing: "LabelName AbsoluteValue (Percentage)"? For example: "Usa 856027 (56 %)".

Is this possible with the right format information in LabelFormat alone (How?) or do I have to use a custom label format (How?) ?

Thank you very much!

Rupert Rand

Answer (score 6):

You can include keywords in the Label property, which can either be set in the GUI(through the Series Collection Editor) or in code.  I would recommend setting it through the GUI since it would not require a full knowledge of the available keywords.  If you instead want to set it in the code, it would look similar to this (assuming I understand what format you are requesting): `Chart.Series(0).Label = "#ValX #Val (#ValPercentY{P0})"`.